# Type confusion with inherited classes

Tags: typescript

I have two pairs of classes that generally represent a generic oauth implementation and an SDK and then a platform specific implementation of those...

```typescript
abstract class PlatformSDK {
  public abstract method1();

  // more
}

class GooglePlatformSDK extends PlatformSDK {
  // implements method defined on abstract class
  public method1() { 
    // does stuff
  }

  // new method defined only on this class
  public method2() { 
    // does different stuff
  }
}

abstract class OAuthHandler {
  public sdk: PlatformSDK;

  // does more stuff
}

class GoogleOAuthHandler extends OAuthHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.sdk = new GooglePlatformSDK();
  }

  // more...
}
```

This all looks great. But I get a compilation error when I instantiate the `GoogleOAuthHandler` and try to access the GooglePlatformSDK.method2() method:

```typescript
const gh = new GoogleOAuthHandler();
gh.sdk.method2();
```

`>> Error: Property 'method2' does not exist on type 'PlatformSDK'`

Any help?

Comment: Please put a `super()` call inside your `GoogleOAuthHandler` constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the `sdk` property of `GoogleOAuthHandler` is `PlatformSDK`, as inherited from the `OAuthHandler` superclass.  Just because you initialize it with an instance of `GooglePlatformSDK` doesn't change that.  If you want the type to be narrower in the subclass, you need to annotate it as such.  Assuming the runtime code acts how you want it, you can use the [`declare` property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) to narrow the type of `sdk` property to `GooglePlatformSDK` without changing the generated JavaScript:

```
class GoogleOAuthHandler extends OAuthHandler {
    declare sdk: GooglePlatformSDK; // <-- here

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.sdk = new GooglePlatformSDK();
    }    
}
```

Now things should behave as you like:

```
const gh = new GoogleOAuthHandler();
gh.sdk.method2(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCqiAzA9lALYDKAIgNIIDeAUAgwgA4CuIyAlrAqJDPAiIBTCAAt8AEwCMACgCUALgQA3fBwkBuWvUYB6XYMJDaAX20o0GAOL58Ac2RDswPIVKUEQgB4QhAOwkMZ1dicio6RgR9BA4iJkdhPwgMYTFJBAkhXA4-IQkEfD8ecGg4RAt0HQZWdi5BEXFpeRoqyKiDCXwhDEgWXFxWs1bo3IB3erT8zOzc-MLkAE8CorEODAqwVprOblTGgCZmiLaGaM7ujI5+oSh-RF7+wdNtXlKBDYQAeQBBFjEACWAAUcUBakW2dTAEgA1kpggRQh4ALwIPwsZDIACEWmGHS6KSMCAeAyGHxs9kcPz+okBwJunh8-kCX1+AKBEhBYMYmQstyJMKU5IcThwCPcFC0kVghT4LHghCOrUiYBYTBu8iVjFWYAAdFDoQgUWMEELHPC3GF5JLGGYhrRpX5IAg7KJDaihONTUIqWy6VArbQXXqYTq9pJDnINO0CtDgAsgA)